# Is the everything-is-arithmetic MySQL specific?

Tags: mysql, sql-standard

Today I learned that `SELECT f1,EXISTS(SELECT ...),f2` is valid in MySQL and, reading from StackOverflow, apparently in PostgreSQL as well and the `EXISTS` part is 0 when the subquery result is empty and 1 when the result is not. Then I began to think and tested a few queries looking like `SELECT * WHERE column1 - column2` and even this worked and it's the same as `column1 <> column2`. And I even tried `WHERE (column1 > 0) - column2` and even this worked. Is this SQL standard or just MySQL is trigger happy about casting booleans and integers with wild abandon? Or perhaps booleans do not even exist in SQL and 0 / 1 represents them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Or perhaps booleans do not even exist in SQL and 0 / 1 represents them*

`boolean` **do** exists in the SQL standard but as "real" booleans.

So valid boolean literals are `false` or `true`.

> *Is this SQL standard or just MySQL is trigger happy about casting booleans and integers with wild abandon*

MySQL does not actually support `boolean` values. It simply treats anything that can't be converted to a non-zero number as "false".

E.g.

```
select *
from some_table
where 'xxxx';
```

is accepted as valid (even though it is invalid SQL) and is equivalent to `where false` because `xxxx` can't be converted to a number and thus is assumed to be `0` which is treated as `false`.

On the other hand

```
select *
from some_table
where '42xxxx';
```

is treated as `where true` because `42xxx` will be (implicitly) converted to `42` which in turn is treated as "true".

---

The query:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE column1 - column2
```

is invalid standard SQL because it yields a number (assuming column1 and column2 are numbers) and a number is not a boolean expression.

---

You can see this behavior when doing:

```
select 1 > 0;
```

MySQL returns the number `1` whereas a database supporting real booleans (e.g. Postgres) will return `true`. Oracle does not support real booleans so `select 1 > 0 from dual` is actually invalid there.

Comment: 42xxx will be (implicitly) converted to 42 -- gosh, here I thought PHP is alone in doing that! So then what about PostgreSQL supporting `SELECT EXISTS()` being 0 or 1?

Comment: `select exists (select * from t);` gives `TRUE` or `FALSE` in Postgres, not 0/1.

Comment: @chx: as Postgres supports real booleans, `exists()` also returns a proper boolean value.

Comment: What a_horse says. You'll have to do an explicit conversion in Postgres to convert that TRUE/FALSE to 1/0: `select (exists (select * from t))::int ;` MySQL does that "automatically" because `BOOLEAN` in MySQL is just a synonym of `TINYINT`, it doesn't have a proper boolean type (but in works and looks like a boolean in most cases).